# comment just attachment .. reply just text ... can I do that?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I want comments just to upload videos without text
but replies the opposite

I mean comments just to upload videos.. without text area
...
in replies its a must to write in text area without any uploads

comments and replies share html form
,comments have css class is called "depth-1"
,replies have css classes like "depth-2".."depth-3".."depth-4".. etc.

so first I want to disabled text area in comments, so I tried this code

```
    add_filter('comment_form_field_comment', 'my_comment_form_field_comment');
function my_comment_form_field_comment($default){
  return false;
}

add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'my_pre_comment_on_post');
function my_pre_comment_on_post($post_id){
  $some_random_value = rand(0, 384534);
  $_POST['comment'] = "Default comment. Some random value to avoid duplicate comment warning: {$some_random_value}";
}
```

but it hide text area for both comments and replies
and I want it just for comments
how I can do that?

Comment: Can you say this using different words with much more information? Are you trying to implement an upload form by using comments?

Comment: I want to make comments just "add file" and replies just write text without any upload for files...can you help for that?

Comment: I explain more in the main post

Comment: Oh, that is not possible with standard WordPress, you would need to rebuild large parts of the commenting system, I estimate several weeks of full-time development work, you are highly unlikely to find a plugin that will do such a specific thing. Comments have text, even if you do not use it. It would be easier to upload video responses using a different mechanism that is not comments, e.g. custom post types. You should have asked how to solve your problem, not how to build your solution ( X Y Problem )

Comment: TLDR: If you want video replies, comments are not the solution. Use a CPT instead and set the post parent, and use a custom loop

Comment: I've also edited out your second question, plugin recommendations are not allowed here, you should look into the software recommendations stack

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you very much, I worked a lot for this and always impasse... and now you make me sure about it ... but I try to make replies by CPT ... I didn't find any thing on google.. do you have tutorial or steps for that.. I didn't use CPT before... all I know after you build your post type you can enable comments